# Updating tables with AJAX, Spring MVC, MySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

How to update my table with AJAX at foreach loop without page refreshing!
Help pls!
This is my jsp code

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="security" %>
<%@page language="java" session="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>Cообщения | Violence and Hate</title>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"/>"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootswatch.less.css"/>"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/variables.less.css"/>"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/CSS/styles.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"
 type="text/css">
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/Jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"/>"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
     data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
      class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
      class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Violence and Hate</a>
   </div>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
    id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

     <li><a href="/app/user">Профиль</a></li>
     <li><a href="/app/user/messages">Сообщения</a></li>
     <li><a href="/app/user/search">Поиск оппонента</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
      data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Информация<span
       class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       <li><a href="/app/user/rules">Правила</a></li>
       <li><a href="/app/user/contacts">Наши контакты</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="/app/user/feedback">Написать администрации</a></li>
      </ul></li>
     <security:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN">
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
       data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Администрирование<span
        class="caret"></span></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="/app/admin">Админка/Список пользователей</a></li>
        <li><a href="/app/admin/feedbacklist">Отзывы/Вопросы/Предложения</a></li>

       </ul></li>
     </security:authorize>
    </ul>

    <c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/j_spring_security_logout" />
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="${logoutUrl}"
     method="post">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Выйти</button>
     <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
      value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
 <img class="img-responsive center-block"  src="<c:url value="/resources/logo/logo.png"/>" />
 <h2 class="text-center">Личные сообщения</h2>
<h5 class="text-center">Чтобы начать общение - выберите оппонента в поиске и отправьте ему сообщение</h5>

   <!-- tabs left -->
   <c:if test="${!empty listDialog}">
      <div class="tabbable tabs-left">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#start" data-toggle="tab">Инфо</a></li>
      <c:forEach items="${listDialog}" var="dialog"> 
          <li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">${dialog.iddialog}</a></li>
          </c:forEach>      
        </ul>
        
        <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- <div class="tab-pane active" id="start">
        Напишите сообщение через поиск!
        </div>
         <div class="tab-pane"  id="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
         Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.</div>
        </div>-->
      </div>
      <!-- /tabs -->
    </div>
</c:if>
</body>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/Jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"/>"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"/>"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

This is my controller method where i'm getting list of dialogs from database

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/messages", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String messagesPage(Model model, Principal principal) {
    model.addAttribute("dialog", new Dialog());
    model.addAttribute("listDialog", dialogService.listDialog(principal.getName()));
    return "messages";

}
```

Here is my DAO method where i'm using SQL query to get info from database

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Dialog> listDialog(String username) {
    String query = "select dialog.iddialog, dialog.username, dialog.reciever from dialog where dialog.username LIKE '%s' OR dialog.reciever LIKE '%s'";
    Session session = null;
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    List<Dialog> dialogList = session.createSQLQuery(String.format(query, username, username)).addEntity(Dialog.class).list();
    session.close();
    session = null;
    return dialogList;
}
```

And here is my SQL code with users table and dialog table

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` ( 
`username` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, 
`enabled` bit(1) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, 
`name` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`surname` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`age` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`weight` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`height` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`sport` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NUlL,
`place` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`photoa` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`photob` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`username`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8; 

CREATE TABLE `user_roles` ( 
`user_role_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
`role` varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
`username` varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`user_role_id`), 
KEY `FK_9ry105icat2dux14oyixybw9l` (`username`), 
CONSTRAINT `FK_9ry105icat2dux14oyixybw9l` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8; 

create table dialog
(
`iddialog` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
`reciever` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`username`varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`iddialog`),
foreign key (`username`) references users(`username`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

Comment: foreach loop are executed on the server, if you dont want to refresh the page you will have to make an JS fonction that do the ajax call and fill the table. You will also have to add a method in your controller that return the data in json format

Comment: @jpprade, thanx for an answer. But i read some info and i can't understand where i need to store AJAX script and how to write function :(

Answer (score 0):

The java method is easy :

just return the datastructure you want and add @ResponseBody in the declartion (you need jackson in the classpath):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/messagesajax", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Dialog> messagesPageAjax(Model model, Principal principal) {
    return dialogService.listDialog(principal.getName());
}
```

Then you have to write a js function and bind it to a DOM event (document load, button click, ...) the function will look like this (Jquery 1):

```
function ajaxFillTable() {

    $.ajax({
        dataType : "json",
        url : '/user/messagesajax',
        headers : {
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        type : 'GET',
        success : function(data) {
            //TODO FILL your table 
            $.each(data,function(key, val) {
                    //TODO
            });

        }
    });
}
```

In the success method you will get your objects in the "data" variable, you can iterate over the list, get properties and append html to the DOM

Comment: thanx for respone! Does i need to put method with @responsebody annotation together with my method or separately?

Comment: I am not sure what is your question but you will have 2 methods : one without the annotation that just return view to render the jsp (this one exists already). One with the annotation that just return raw data in json format

Comment: does i need to store ajax script at my jsp with table?

Comment: you can have js directly in the jsp, but its better to have it in a separate file :<script src="<c:url value="/resources/main.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I made it without controllers.
1. Created ajax script

```
        <script>
    function getDialogs()
    {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/app/user/dialogs', 
        success: function(r) 
        { 
            $('#dialogs').html(r);

            console.log(r); 
        }, 
        error : function(r){ alert(r); }});
    }
    setInterval(getDialogs, 1000);

</script>
```

2. Created dialogs.jsp and putted there a part of code that i need to update. And that's all